# Firing mouse event click from code

Tags: c#, winforms, operating-system

I want fire the mouse click event from my code. I dont have any idea how will i do it. Please suggest some useful tips and tricks. I am developing a window application using c#.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
button.PerformClick();
```